# ngTable - Bind Selected Item to TextArea

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have an ngTable, and I want to Bind one of the values of the currently selected item to a textarea below the ngTable. So when you edit the textarea, the ngTable is updated with that value for that specific selected item.

I am pasting a piece of my code. All data populates from a service call... so I am good there. Just need to know how to Bind the textarea with the currently selected item's Notes field.

http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/22

I have an ngtable as such:

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="phoneCalls in $data">
                    <td data-title="'Case SSN'">{{phoneCalls.employeeSsn}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Call Reason'">{{phoneCalls.callRsn}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Call Receive Date'">{{phoneCalls.callCompleteDt}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Call Type'">{{phoneCalls.callType}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Call For'">{{phoneCalls.callFor}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Caller Name'">{{phoneCalls.callerName}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Callback Number'">{{phoneCalls.callbackNo}}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Notes'">{{phoneCalls.callNoteDesc}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Let's say I want a textarea below this ngTable and I want to Bind it to the Notes column in the ngTable. If I edit the textarea, I want the ngTable Notes column (for the selected item) to update. Any idea how to make this work?